# Can I use a correlation test function with a correlation matrix as an imput?

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to apply a correlation test function to a correlation matrix and I'm having no success. I don't have the raw data just this matrix, this is why is important to find a way in which I can do this.

My data looks like this:

```
      PM10     T  Tmax  Tmin     P     H    PT     V  Vmax
PM10  1.00 -0.41 -0.26 -0.55  0.37 -0.13 -0.25 -0.27 -0.22
T    -0.41  1.00  0.95  0.87 -0.18 -0.28 -0.01 -0.14 -0.05
Tmax -0.26  0.95  1.00  0.70 -0.08 -0.41 -0.09 -0.23 -0.08
Tmin -0.55  0.87  0.70  1.00 -0.30  0.07  0.14 -0.03 -0.01
P     0.37 -0.18 -0.08 -0.30  1.00 -0.18 -0.13 -0.29 -0.25
H    -0.13 -0.28 -0.41  0.07 -0.18  1.00  0.32 -0.15 -0.19
PT   -0.25 -0.01 -0.09  0.14 -0.13  0.32  1.00  0.11  0.07
V    -0.27 -0.14 -0.23 -0.03 -0.29 -0.15  0.11  1.00  0.83
Vmax -0.22 -0.05 -0.08 -0.01 -0.25 -0.19  0.07  0.83  1.00
```

Cor.test() doesn't accept a matrix as input and I can't seem to find any other way in which I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Barlett's test tests a correlation matrix against the identity based on a chi squared approximation to the distribution of the determinant of the correlation matrix.  The sample size, n, should be supplied but if not it will assume 100 -- see warning below.

If the p value is less than 0.05, say, then we can reject the null hypothesis that the correlation matrix is an identity matrix.  Apply it to an identity matrix `cortest.bartlett(diag(9))` and a matrix of all ones `cortest.bartlett(1 + 0*R)` to see the difference.

```
library(psych)
cortest.bartlett(R)
```

giving:

```
$chisq
[1] 777.2996

$p.value
[1] 5.038841e-140

$df
[1] 36

Warning message:
In cortest.bartlett(R) : n not specified, 100 used
```

### Note

```
R <- structure(c(1, -0.41, -0.26, -0.55, 0.37, -0.13, -0.25, -0.27, 
-0.22, -0.41, 1, 0.95, 0.87, -0.18, -0.28, -0.01, -0.14, -0.05, 
-0.26, 0.95, 1, 0.7, -0.08, -0.41, -0.09, -0.23, -0.08, -0.55, 
0.87, 0.7, 1, -0.3, 0.07, 0.14, -0.03, -0.01, 0.37, -0.18, -0.08, 
-0.3, 1, -0.18, -0.13, -0.29, -0.25, -0.13, -0.28, -0.41, 0.07, 
-0.18, 1, 0.32, -0.15, -0.19, -0.25, -0.01, -0.09, 0.14, -0.13, 
0.32, 1, 0.11, 0.07, -0.27, -0.14, -0.23, -0.03, -0.29, -0.15, 
0.11, 1, 0.83, -0.22, -0.05, -0.08, -0.01, -0.25, -0.19, 0.07, 
0.83, 1), .Dim = c(9L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(c("PM10", "T", "Tmax", 
"Tmin", "P", "H", "PT", "V", "Vmax"), c("PM10", "T", "Tmax", 
"Tmin", "P", "H", "PT", "V", "Vmax")))
```